# Indicate reverse of graph transition

Tags: graph-theory

I have the following (directed) graph:

A --> B

the transition is labled C. Is there symbol to denote the inverse of the (A,B) transtion?

Comment: Did you mean in a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_transition_system labelled transition system”?

Comment: I'm not aware of any standard notation, you can just invent one.

Answer (score 1):

As Yuval mentioned there's no direct simple standard notation. But:

- a directed graph is a relation, and this  an be represented by a square adjacency matrix $A$, so the graph with all edges reversed has the transposed adjacency matrix $A^T$.
- in category theory, for a given category $C$, the same objects and the reverse of all arrows as $C$ is called $C^{op}$.